# Why doesn't my script accept characters?

Tags: java, jquery, sql, database

In my SQL the echo $row['ans'] are type varchar(11): JAN,FEB,MAR,APR. I do know now why it won't be displayed out, but when I change JAN,FEB,MAR,APR into numbers it works. Please impart you knowledge and understanding to me. Thanks!

choice box

```
  var months = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","',explode(",",$rows['ans'])).'"'; ?> ];
  months.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );
  for ( var i=0; i<4; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + months[i] + '</div>').data( 'months', i ).appendTo( '#monthPile' ).draggable( {
      //containment: '#content',
      stack: '#monthPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }
```

Create the slots

```
  var slot = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","',explode(",",$rows['ans'])).'"'; ?> ];
  for ( var i=0; i<=3; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + slot[i] + '</div>').data( 'months', i ).appendTo( '#monthSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#monthPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}
```

Comment: Please show us the rendered script, not the script with php tags in it.

Comment: you mean those that has the <script> tag??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When injecting strings into javascript you need to put "" around those characters to tell that its a string. Your numbers work because with out the "" javascript interprets those characters as numbers. Try using the php implode function to add double quotes around your strings in the array (this is assuming $row['ans'] holds an array)

Update working example:

```
<?php
$rows = array(
    "ans" => "JAN,FEB,MAR"
);
?>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = [<?php echo '"'. implode('","',explode(",",$rows['ans'])) . '"'; ?>];
    document.write(test.toString());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me i tried the implode function however my output instead of nothing it comes out something but is still in a mass. i tried manually putting " " for my JAN,FEB,MAR,APR in my database but still cant work. Any other way? sorry i'm quite new to this.

Comment: If $rows['ans'] is holding a string you would need to do the following <?php echo '"'. implode('","',explode(",",$rows['ans'])) . '"' ?>

Comment: my $rows['ans] is holding a string: JAN,FEB,MAR,APR. so i just have to do the above you mention right? but i still cant get the output.

Comment: Take it from the answer not from my comment. Show me the rendered code from CTRL+U (Firefox) to view source so i can see what the output is. Also in your second code example u reference an array called words that does not exist, should it be slot instead?

Comment: i have the code from Firefox erm but how do i display it here? So sorry about it.

Comment: use a back tick to put code in `code`, just paste the line where u put your array values in or edit your original post

Comment: What happens when you run this? Errors? Anything displayed? After you run this show me the code the is created, view source on the page and show me.

Comment: it didnt show any error just that nothing is being displayed out. (sorry i cant post the img of the output, not enough privileges.)

Comment: Ok i view the page source it says undefined variable. at both my line Var slot and months

Comment: Simplify your code. Take everything out and try to echo your PHP variable, if it is not displayed then your php is wrong. If it is then just do the echo on the month array....

Comment: when try to echo $row[ans] out from the script it works but when you put it inside the array it failed.

Comment: my database for ans is just :JAN,FEB,MAR,APR i just dont understand why when you put it inside the array it cant work.

Comment: Can you send me your whole PHP file somehow? Paste it above

Comment: is too long cant paste all of it. :(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wkbPCHTs
sorry if its abit messy was doing some try and error.

Comment: I have made a simple version of what you sent me, try that and paste the source of what i gave you back to pastebin and send me the lnk so i can see.  http://pastebin.com/9PKPS4gn

Comment: Stop YOU ARE REFERENCING YOUR PHP VARIABLE AS $rows its $row

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me finally is out.Really really appreciate it!

Comment: cant add need 15 reputation,again really thanks you for taking your time to help me out. :)